# Table used in Hungarian method for solving assignment problem

Tags: tables

[image]

How to type the table used in the Hungarian method to solve assignment problems.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE: have you some experience with LaTeX?

Comment: I had some experience. I can type simple mathematical symbols but the above table is difficult for me. How to type it?

Comment: For the table not there is more effort; but for the horizontal and vertical lines it is necessary to know TikZ, pstricks, metapost, asympote package to draw them.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to do that with the environment `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

That environment is similar to the classical environment `{array}` (of `array`) but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns of the tabular.

So, it's possible to use Tikz to draw whatever rule you want after the construction of the main array.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amssymb} % \checkmark

\begin{document}

\[\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{NiceArray}{>{\rule[-2.8mm]{0pt}{8mm}}ccccccc}%
  [
    columns-width=8mm ,
    corners = {NW,NE} ,
    hvlines ,
    code-before = \arraycolor{cyan!10}
  ]
  & I  & II  & III & IV & V \\
A & 5  & [0] & 3   & 10 & 40 & \NotEmpty \\
B & 7  & 8   & 9   & 14 & 41 & {\scriptsize\checkmark}(5)   \\
C & 11 & 15  & 16  & 17 & 42                                \\
D & 12 & 18  & 19  & 20 & 31 & {\scriptsize\checkmark}(3)   \\
E & 13 & 21  & 22  & 23 & 74 & {\scriptsize\checkmark}(1)   \\
& \overset{\checkmark}{(4)} & & & \overset{\checkmark}{(2)} \\
\CodeAfter 
  \tikz \draw (2.5-|2) -- (2.5-|7) 
              (4.5-|2) -- (4.5-|7) 
              (2-|2.5) -- (7-|2.5) 
              (2-|6.5) -- (7-|6.5) ;
\end{NiceArray}\]

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: This is better than with my Mathcha :-)

Answer (score 3):

My new welcome. After many improved there is a table for you created with [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor)/`TikZ` that it is a fast tool online. It is not very easy to create but I leave to you to put the exact numbers into the cells. If you see the code you can find the corrispondence numbers.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (117,34) -- (167,34) -- (167,84) -- (117,84) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (167,34) -- (217,34) -- (217,84) -- (167,84) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (217,34) -- (267,34) -- (267,84) -- (217,84) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (267,34) -- (317,34) -- (317,84) -- (267,84) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (317,34) -- (367,34) -- (367,84) -- (317,84) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (117,84) -- (167,84) -- (167,134) -- (117,134) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (67,84) -- (117,84) -- (117,134) -- (67,134) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (167,84) -- (217,84) -- (217,134) -- (167,134) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (217,84) -- (267,84) -- (267,134) -- (217,134) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (267,84) -- (317,84) -- (317,134) -- (267,134) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (317,84) -- (367,84) -- (367,134) -- (317,134) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (367,84) -- (417,84) -- (417,134) -- (367,134) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (67,134) -- (117,134) -- (117,184) -- (67,184) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (117,134) -- (167,134) -- (167,184) -- (117,184) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (167,134) -- (217,134) -- (217,184) -- (167,184) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (217,134) -- (267,134) -- (267,184) -- (217,184) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (267,134) -- (317,134) -- (317,184) -- (267,184) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (317,134) -- (367,134) -- (367,184) -- (317,184) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (367,134) -- (417,134) -- (417,184) -- (367,184) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (67,184) -- (117,184) -- (117,234) -- (67,234) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (117,184) -- (167,184) -- (167,234) -- (117,234) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (267,184) -- (317,184) -- (317,234) -- (267,234) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (317,184) -- (367,184) -- (367,234) -- (317,234) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (367,184) -- (417,184) -- (417,234) -- (367,234) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (167,184) -- (217,184) -- (217,234) -- (167,234) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (217,184) -- (267,184) -- (267,234) -- (217,234) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (67,234) -- (117,234) -- (117,284) -- (67,284) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (217,234) -- (267,234) -- (267,284) -- (217,284) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (167,234) -- (217,234) -- (217,284) -- (167,284) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (267,234) -- (317,234) -- (317,284) -- (267,284) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (117,234) -- (167,234) -- (167,284) -- (117,284) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (367,234) -- (417,234) -- (417,284) -- (367,284) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (317,234) -- (367,234) -- (367,284) -- (317,284) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (67,284) -- (117,284) -- (117,334) -- (67,334) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (117,284) -- (167,284) -- (167,334) -- (117,334) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (167,284) -- (217,284) -- (217,334) -- (167,334) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (217,284) -- (267,284) -- (267,334) -- (217,334) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (267,284) -- (317,284) -- (317,334) -- (267,334) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (317,284) -- (367,284) -- (367,334) -- (317,334) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (367,284) -- (417,284) -- (417,334) -- (367,334) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (67,334) -- (117,334) -- (117,384) -- (67,384) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (117,334) -- (167,334) -- (167,384) -- (117,384) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (167,334) -- (217,334) -- (217,384) -- (167,384) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (217,334) -- (267,334) -- (267,384) -- (217,384) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (267,334) -- (317,334) -- (317,384) -- (267,384) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (317,334) -- (367,334) -- (367,384) -- (317,384) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 161; green, 250; blue, 253 }  ,fill opacity=0.67 ] (367,334) -- (417,334) -- (417,384) -- (367,384) -- cycle ;
\draw (139,52.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$I$};
\draw (184,52.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$II$};
\draw (230,52.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$III$};
\draw (280,52.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$IV$};
\draw (334,52.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$V$};
\draw (84,101.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$A$};
\draw (83,151.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$B$};
\draw (83,205.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$C$};
\draw (83,252.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$D$};
\draw (84,299.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$E$};
\draw (133,340) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\overset{\checkmark}{(4)}$};
\draw (283,340) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\overset{\checkmark}{(2)}$};
\draw (134,102.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$5$};
\draw (181,102.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\boldsymbol{[0]}$};
\draw (238,102.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$3$};
\draw (134,153.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$7$};
\draw (130,201.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$11$};
\draw (236,153.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$9$};
\draw (185,153.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$8$};
\draw (283,102.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$10$};
\draw (131,250.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$12$};
\draw (131,300.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$13$};
\draw (283,153.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$14$};
\draw (181,201.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$15$};
\draw (232,201.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$16$};
\draw (283,201.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$17$};
\draw (181,250.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$18$};
\draw (232,251.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$19$};
\draw (283,251.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$20$};
\draw (182,300.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$21$};
\draw (232,300.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$22$};
\draw (282,300.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$23$};
\draw (333,102.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$40$};
\draw (334,153.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$41$};
\draw (333,201.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$42$};
\draw (333,251.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$31$};
\draw (332,300.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$74$};
\draw (380,153.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\checkmark(5)$};
\draw (380,251.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\checkmark(3)$};
\draw (380,300.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\checkmark(1)$};
\draw    (118,111) -- (367,111) ;
\draw    (118,209) -- (367,209) ;
\draw    (142,85) -- (142,333) ;
\draw    (342,85) -- (342,333) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the lines need to continue to the end of their respective boxes. For example the two lines going through 5 stop too early.

Comment: @Anush Please, can you see now if is it good?